# C# and Oracle 12g - connection pooling for application that runs every minute

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, connection-pooling

We have a service that runs every minute that calls a console app. The console app connects to oracle/executes a query/close connection on each execution then exits.

I know connection pooling is the ability to reuse connections to minimize the effects of having to connect and disconnect to the database each time by grabbing a available connection.

My question is, how does connection pooling work for the setup that I mentioned above? Since the console app program exits every time, on the next run, does it utilize connection pooling or does it create new instances every run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is no sharing of connection pool connections over different running instances of an application. So if you close any application its connection pool connections will be closed. Each time a application starts you will start a new connection pool for that application.

Comment: Thanks, with this setup i guess it is best to disable the connection pool.